# What do i change to get the problem right?

Tags: java, math

[This the formula that needed to be code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBiCh.jpg)

Ive tried this code but the answer is different from the given problem

Pls see picture for the formula, I've d this code but it seems like the values are different so I get different answers

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Problem 6");
        System.out.println("Input x and y");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        double z = 2 * Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,3);
        
        System.out.println(z / 2);
        
    }
}
```

Ive tried this code but it doesnt show the right answer

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Problem 6");
        System.out.println("Input x and y");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        double z = 2 * Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,3);
        
        System.out.println(z / 2);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match the problem.  The problem requires you to read X and compute Y.  What your code is doing is reading X and Y and computing Z ... using a different formula.   Is your code a genuine attempt?  (It is hard to understand how you could have gotten this code from the requirements ... assuming you read them.)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of your requirements.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As an aside: The notation used in the image in unclear. As fas ar I know, there is no semantic to the syntax `(y = 2x^2 + 4) / 2`. It could mean `y = (2x^2 +4) / 2`; it could mean `y / 2 = (2x^2 +4) / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

According to you picture with the formula.
I think you would get the value of y with x like so :

```
    double y = (2 * Math.pow(x,2) + 4)/3;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Only `x` needs to be inputted from the console, the equation is to find `y`, so there is no need for it to be inputted from the console.
2. There is no need for `z`, in the equation there are only two variables, you can assign the result to `y`.
3. I also don't understand this `Math.pow(y,3);`, there is nowhere said in the question to take `y` to the power of 3.

The equation by the code will be like this

```
double y = ((2 * Math.pow(x, 2)) + 4) / 3;
```